# How do I store a discord message in a variable?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am just trying to store the users response in a variable. I'm using python and discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Whats your name?')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the message content into a command \[discord.py\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66722825/get-the-message-content-into-a-command-discord-py)

Comment: I think you are asking to store the user message that would be in response to the bot's message "Whats your name?". And how are you detecting the user's response? Would it be a direct reply to the message, or just the next message in that channel, next message that mentions the bot, etc.

Comment: Are you trying to get them to *respond* and then getting the content of that?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel

    await ctx.send('Whats your name?')
    msg = await bot.wait_for("message",check=check, timeout=30)
    await ctx.send(f"Your name is {msg.content}")
```

This function ensures that the message author and channel are the same

```py
def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel
```

And this is just a built in method to discord.py that gets the content of the user's next message

```py
msg = await bot.wait_for("message",check=check, timeout=30)
```

I would highly suggest [reading the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)